# Check if other tabs are open

Tags: javascript, html

I've tried coding a function that checks if other tabs are active, and if they are it should close them and open another tab, and if not it should just open the tab. I'm new at javascript and tried this but it didn't work.

#### HTML

```
<div class="showRatings">

<li role="presentation id="productInfomation" class="active">...</li>
<li role="presentation id="productDiscount">...</li>
<li role="presentation id="productRatings">...</li>
```

#### Js Script

```
$('div.showRatings').click(function(){
if ( document.getElementById('productInfomation').classList.contains('active') ) {
    document.getElementById('productInfomation').classList.remove('active');
    document.getElementById('productRatings').classList.add('active');
} else if ( document.getElementById('productDiscount').classList.contains('active') ) {
    document.getElementById('productDiscount').classList.remove('active');
    document.getElementById('productRatings').classList.add('active');
} else {
    document.getElementById('productRatings').classList.add('active');
}});
```

Comment: In your click event. Loop over li elements and check wether they got an active class attribute and act accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to write code for each element separately, or even bother to test which tab was previously active. Just remove the "active" class from all of them in one go, and then add it to the element that was clicked:

```
$('.showRatings li').on("click", function() {
    $('.showRatings li.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but for some reason it still doesn't work. My site is under maintenance, so unless i have your ip's i can't link to the problem.

Comment: You shouldn't link to the problem in any case; the question should contain a [mcve].  Can you be more specific than "it doesn't work"?

Comment: (Just to confirm, are you using jQuery?  Your code is a mixture of jQuery `$('.div.showRatings')` and vanilla js methods `document.getElementById` so I assumed jQuery was ok; but if you don't have jQuery installed that would explain why this isn't working for you.  Are you seeing error messages of any kind in the console?)

Comment: Yea makes sense. But i think that it easily could be because its placed in the global.js file. And i guess that doesn't work since its jQuery?

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean there. Assuming jQuery is linked into the page before you try to use any of it, you can use it from within any .js file. Do you see `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: $` in the console? If so, then you're missing jQuery (or linking it in too late.) If not then something else is going on.